# Function argument as a part of the output name

Tags: r, function, arguments

Perhaps a silly question, but I can't find any answers to it anywhere (that I've looked :P ). I am trying to create a function with two arguments, these will be vectors (e.g.x=c(a,b,c) and y=c(50,75,100)). I will write a function which calculates all the combinations of these and have the argument used as a part of the output name. E.g.

function(x,y)
df$output_a_50 = a*2+50^2
df$output_a_75 = a*2+75^2
.....

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: Seems to be two questions: to get all combinations you need either expand.grid() (will lead to a slow solution) or outer() if you can vectorize. Then the other bit is on constructing names: something like outer(x,y, function(foo,bar) paste("output",foo,bar, sep = "_")) which you can assign to the output as names(df) <- xyz before returning

Comment: I am only interested in the part regarding construction of the name :)

Comment: One problem is that y=c(a,b,c) will lose the names. How is the function going to work out which bits of y are a,b, and c? You are probably better off doing foo=function(yvalues,...) and getting the other variables from the ... list. Although I'm not sure you can get the names from the ... without some real trickery. Your problem also is that 'a' isn't in the function environment. I think you are probably approaching the problem in completely the wrong way here...

Comment: @Spacedman I think Endre should have defined his input as `x=c('a','b','c')` .  Then it's just a matter of `paste(x[i],'*2+',y[i],'^2',collapse='')` to get what he wants.

Comment: i think @Carl solution in conjunction with the `assign` function help you.

Comment: @Carl if you put the names in quotes you then have to evaluate 'a' in the context of the caller. Making the names for df is easy, evaluating the RHS not so.

Answer (score 2):

As @Spacedman and others discussed, your problem is that if you pass `c(a, b, c)` to your function, the names will be lost. The best alternative in my opinion, is to pass a list:

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
   df <- list()
   for (xx in names(x)) {
      for (yy in y) {
         varname <- paste("output", xx, yy, sep = "_")
         df[[varname]] <- x[[xx]]*2 + yy^2
      }
   }
   df
}

foo(x = list(a = NA, b = 1, c = 2:3),
    y = c(50, 75, 100))

# $output_a_50
# [1] NA
# 
# $output_a_75
# [1] NA
# 
# $output_a_100
# [1] NA
# 
# $output_b_50
# [1] 2502
# 
# $output_b_75
# [1] 5627
# 
# $output_b_100
# [1] 10002
# 
# $output_c_50
# [1] 2504 2506
# 
# $output_c_75
# [1] 5629 5631
# 
# $output_c_100
# [1] 10004 10006
```